# FullCalendar Routing with Symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony, fullcalendar

Hallo i have problems with my FullCalendar app in Symfony2.

Im not sure but i think an error in my route.

This is my code in the FullCalendar.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('pspiess_letsplay_booking_add') }}',
                data: {"title": title, "start": start, "end": end},
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(result) {
                            alert('OK');
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                alert('Time out error.');
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                            } else {
                                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                })
```

This is my route

```
pspiess_letsplay_booking_add:
    pattern:  /admin/booking/add
    defaults: { _controller: pspiessLetsplayBundle:Booking:add }
```

This is my controller

```
    /**
 * Lists all Booking entities for Calendar.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="booking_add")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function addReservation() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('b')
            ->from('pspiessLetsplayBundle:Booking', 'b');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $jsonContent = $query->getResult();

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($jsonContent as $obj) {
        $rows[] = array(
            'title' => "test",
            'start' => $obj->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'end' => $obj->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'className' => 'label-success',
        );
    }

    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($rows, 'json');

    return array(
        'entities' => $jsonContent,
    );
}
```

Is there some tutorials how to use the FullCalendar with Symfony2? I searched the whole web, but i dont found anything...

Comment: I've successfully implemented FullCalendar with Symfony2. From what I see right now, the biggest error is that your `controller` method does not end with `Action` so it should be named `addReservation`. Second, you haven't shown us `pspiessLetsplayBundle:Booking:add` method. Also, I `json_decode` and again `json_encode` serialized objects to strip off all the Entity attributes. Try these few things and we'll see where we at with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, i will try you suggestions. Do you have some smaple code? Im really stuck at this momemt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some Problems in my code. Here is a sample, it works fine for me.

My controller action

```
    public function addReservationAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //fetch the POST Data
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $data = $request->request->all();

        //save the Reservation
        $booking = new Booking();

        $booking->setTitle($data["title"]);
        $booking->setStart(new \DateTime($data["start"]));
        $booking->setEnd(new \DateTime($data["end"]));

        $em->persist($booking);
        $em->flush();

        //return response
        $serializedEntity = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($booking, 'json');
        $response = new Response($serializedEntity);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
}
```

My Route

```
pspiess_letsplay_booking_add:
pattern:  /admin/booking/add
defaults: { _controller: pspiessLetsplayBundle:Booking:addReservation }
```

My Script code

```
      $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('pspiess_letsplay_booking_add') }}',
            data: {"title": title, "start": start, "end": end},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                }, true);
                $(".title").val(""); // clear title field
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            },
        })
```